# Java ClassNotFoundException while running spring mvc web-app

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I have created one dynamic web project using spring MVC. But while running it 
on server I got the below exception.SEVERE:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/core/env/ConfigurableEnvironment
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2389)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2699)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.java:1985)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:104)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(Contex tLoader.java:348)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:281)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4205)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4704)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1053)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:840)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1053)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:463)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:525)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:754)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
org.springframework.core.env.ConfigurableEnvironment
06-Apr-2016 07:00:39 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart

SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of 
class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/core/env/ConfigurableEnvironment
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2389)
```

For your reference here are the jars that I used.

```
    spring-asm-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar
    spring-beans-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar
    spring-context-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar
    spring-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar
    spring-expression-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar
    spring-web-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar
    spring-webmvc-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar
    commons-logging-api-1.1.jar
    jstl-1.2.jar
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/env/ConfigurableEnvironment.html)
this class is available since version 3.1, but you have 3.0.

Comment: Thanks for answer....But now I changed all spring jars to version 3.2.6 and now i am getting below error.                                                                                                               java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/beans/factory/ListableBeanFactory

Comment: From the current data I cannot give any advises. How the WAR is built? Where are the libraries copied? What web server is used?

Comment: what informations u need tell me i will share those also??